# Partial derivatives of piecewise multivariable function when $(x,y)=(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, partial-derivative

Function is $g(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with  $$
   g(x,y) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}+i\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2} & : (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\
       0 & : (x,y)=(0,0)
     \end{array}
   \right.$$
With g(x,y)=$u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$.

> I want to show that $\partial_xu(0,0)=\partial_yv(0,0)$ and $\partial_yu(0,0)=\partial_xv(0,0)$.

But all the partial derivatives I find have the term $(x^2+y^2)^2$ in the denominator. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the definition of partial derivative:

For example,

$\partial_xu(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\left ( \frac{1}{h}\left ( \frac{(0+h)^2(0)}{(0+h)^2+(0)^2}-0 \right )  \right )=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{0}{h^{3}}=0$

Comment: What is the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ term? And shouldn't the denominator in your limit become $r^{3}$?

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the magnitude of $(x,y)$. the denominator is $r^{1/2}\cdot r^2=r^{5/2}$.

Comment: So youre saying $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r^{1/2}$ and $x^2+y^2=r^2$, or am I just not seeing something?

Comment: my mistake. I was calulating something else- I will fix it!